# In Azure , how can we set CacheDependency with database -Redis Cache

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-redis-cache

Suppose other system updates the data in DB , how can we set the cache dependency in Redis-cache to get it updated with new version of data. ?

We used to do it with .net Cahing framework..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency(v=vs.110).aspx